# Invites do not get sent for calendar events (G Suite)

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm coding a Javascript application that creates events using the Calendar API. The event gets added correctly to the calendars of all participants, however, attendees are not seeing invites in their inbox. All participants (logged in user, organizer and attendees) are part of the same G Suite organization. Here's the request I'm sending, grabbed from Chrome:

```
Request URL:https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?sendNotifications=true&alt=json
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200

Body:
{ "summary":"Test event",
  "description":"",
  "location":"",
  "start":{
    "dateTime":"2017-01-16T12:00:00.000Z"
  },"end":{
    "dateTime":"2017-01-16T12:30:00.000Z"
  },"attendees":[
    {
      "email":"redacted"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there anything specific to G Suite that needs to be done to send the invite?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've seen that events gets added correctly, you might just need to [Customize your notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242) which is the given resolution from [G Suite Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1084817?hl=en).

Aside from that, you may [enable or disable external invitation prompts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6329284?hl=en). As an administrator, you may want to check if the prompt is enabled for your domain or for organizational units within your domain.

Here are the steps:

1. [Sign in](https://admin.google.com/) to your **Google Admin console**. Sign in using your administrator account (does not end in @gmail.com).
2. From the dashboard, go to **Apps > G Suite > Calendar > Sharing Settings > External invitations**.
3. Choose ON or OFF for the setting.

Hope that helps!